# How can I count the characters of a Simple Text Box and Output this to an Order page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.

I have created a Custom Field on the Product Page, whereby shoppers are able to enter their custom text which they would like to see on the associated product.

I have managed to be able to Output the Custom Field's content to the subsequent Order page, however, is anyone aware of how I can count the characters entered by the shopper into said Custom Field and then Output this Character Count to the Order page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer to a similar question to mine, try this ...

**JavaScript/jQuery**

Place the below code within the page template you would like such a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = jQuery(this).val().length;
    jQuery('#letter_count').text(cs);
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

Within your functions.php file, enter the below code as to Output your function:

```
<?php
function letter_counting(){
    echo '<span id="letter_count"></span>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'letter_counting', 29);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's Strlen function on your input. Like:

```
echo strlen($inputvariable);
```

This outputs the length of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  How would I 'link' this with the Custom Field as obviously, it would not be myself entering the text but a shopper.  An example here, would be hugely appreciated.